# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre ISOc++11 y GNUc++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre el estándar **ISOc++11** y **GNUc++11** a la hora de compilar el código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La compilación ISO se trata del estándar C++11 sin más, mientras que GNU incluye las extensiones propias de GNU.

En ambos casos vas a poder hacer uso del estándar C++11. La opción más portable es la ISO ya que hacer uso de las extensiones GNU impide que el código compile en sistemas no compatibles con GNU. Si tu programa compila con ISO entonces también lo hará con GNU, pero lo contrario no está garantizado.

Para revisar las extensiones de la compilación con GNU puedes visitar el siguiente [enlace](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html)